# How to Create Multiple List of Tuple From Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples

I have a Pandas Data Frame which contain Three Column. I want to create a multiple list of tuple based on the value in Project Column

```
print (df)
   Project  Resource  Time
0       P1         0     4
1       P1         2     4
2       P1         1    10
3       P1         3     3
4       P2         1     3
5       P2         3    10
6       P2         0    11
7       P2         2     3
8       P2         0    12
9       P2         3    11
10      P2         1     3
11      P2         2     3
12      P3         0    12
```

List Tuple i want to create look like this
[[(0,4),(2,4),(1,10),(3,3)],[(1,3),(3,10),(0,11),(2,3),(0,12),(3,11),(1,3),(2,3)],[(0,12)]]

I used the following code

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in data.values]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with lambda function and `zip`, last convert output `Series` to `list`:

```
t  = df.groupby('Project').apply(lambda x: list(zip(x['Resource'], x['Time']))).tolist()
print (t)
[[(0, 4), (2, 4), (1, 10), (3, 3)], 
 [(1, 3), (3, 10), (0, 11), (2, 3), (0, 12), (3, 11), (1, 3), (2, 3)],
 [(0, 12)]]
```

Another solution:

```
t  = (df.groupby('Project')['Resource','Time']
        .apply(lambda x: [tuple(y) for y in x.values])
        .tolist())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `zip` function to iterate over several columns of a pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ressource":[0,2, 1,3], "time":[4,4, 10, 3]})

tuples = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(df['ressource'], df['time'])]
```

---

Output:

```
[(0, 4), (2, 4), (1, 10), (3, 3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> df['zip'] = tuple(zip(df.Resource, df.Time))
>>> df.groupby('Project').agg(lambda x:list(x))['zip'].tolist()
[[(0, 4), (2, 4), (1, 10), (3, 3)],
 [(1, 3), (3, 10), (0, 11), (2, 3), (0, 12), (3, 11), (1, 3), (2, 3)],
 [(0, 12)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
listExample=[]
for code in tmpa.loc[:, 'Project'].unique():
   listExample.append([(a, b) for a, b in tmpa[tmpa.loc[:, 'Project']==code].loc[:, ['Resource', 'Time']].values])
```

It's not pretty, but it should work I think.